# Google Maps API zoom on resize

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have searched, researched and searched some more.

I am desperately trying to make it so my map changes its zoom automatically with different browser sizes as it keeps the markers on the map viewable. Right now the best thing that works for me is:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "resize", function() {
var center = map.getCenter();
google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
map.setCenter(center);
```

And even that is flawed. When the map becomes smaller, say on a mobile device, the markers eventually leave visibility since the zoom does not change. I need the zoom to change. Seemingly, this is the solution(I've done a lot of research, mostly from Stack Overflow):

```
map.fitBounds(firstB,secondB);
```

firstB, and secondB are the latitude and longitude that my markers use for their position.

I've even tried:

```
bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
bounds.extend(marker);
bounds.extend(smarker);
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

Currently this is what I have:

```
<script>
var geocoder;
var map;

function initialize() {
  firstB = new google.maps.LatLng(38.9395799,-104.7168500999999);
  secondB = new google.maps.LatLng(38.9382571,-104.71727069999997);
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(38.938987, -104.717286);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom:18,
    center:latlng,
    disableDefaultUI:true
  }

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
  map.fitBounds(firstB,secondB);

  var styles=[
  {
    featureType:"road",
    elementType:"labels",
    stylers:[
      {visibility:"off"}
    ]
  }
  ];
  map.setOptions({styles: styles});

var pinIcon = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
    'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png',
    null, /* size is determined at runtime */
    null, /* origin is 0,0 */
    null, /* anchor is bottom center of the scaled image */
    new google.maps.Size(52, 52)
);  

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: firstB,
      map: map,
      title: 'AVS',
      icon:pinIcon,
  }); 

  var firstB_contentString = '<div><p>Medical Office Building</p><a href="MOB/architectural-layout.html"><p class="infoContent">6007 E Woodmen Rd.</p><p class="infoContent">Colorado Springs, CO 80923</p></p></a></div>';

  var firstB_infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: firstB_contentString
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
  firstB_infowindow.open(map,marker);
});

  var smarker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: secondB,
      map: map,
      title: 'AVS',
      icon:'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png'
  }); 
  var secondB_contentString = '<div><p>General Hospital</p><a href="MAIN/architectural-layout.html"><p class="infoContent">6001 E. Woodmen Rd.</p><p class="infoContent">Colorado Springs, CO 80923</p></a></div>';

  var secondB_infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: secondB_contentString
  });
google.maps.event.addListener(smarker, 'click', function() {
  secondB_infowindow.open(map,smarker);
});

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'mousedown', function() {
  firstB_infowindow.close(map,marker);
  secondB_infowindow.close(map,smarker);
});
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mousedown', function() {
  firstB_infowindow.close();
  secondB_infowindow.close();
});
google.maps.event.addListener(smarker, 'mousedown', function() {
  firstB_infowindow.close();
  secondB_infowindow.close();
});

/*bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
bounds.extend(marker);
bounds.extend(smarker);
map.fitBounds(bounds);*/

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);


/*google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "resize", function() {
 var center = map.getCenter();
 google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
 map.setCenter(center);
});*/

    </script>
```

Nothing works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix your `bounds`, make that global and call map.fitBounds in the resize handler code:

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

function initialize() {
  var firstB = new google.maps.LatLng(38.9395799,-104.7168500999999);
  var secondB = new google.maps.LatLng(38.9382571,-104.71727069999997);
  bounds.extend(firstB);
  bounds.extend(secondB);
```

Then:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "resize", function() {
 google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
 map.fitBounds(bounds);
});
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qxghx2g4/1/)

code snippet:

```js
var geocoder;
var map;
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

function initialize() {
  var firstB = new google.maps.LatLng(38.9395799,-104.7168500999999);
  var secondB = new google.maps.LatLng(38.9382571,-104.71727069999997);
    bounds.extend(firstB);
    bounds.extend(secondB);
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(38.938987, -104.717286);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom:18,
    center:latlng,
    disableDefaultUI:true
  }

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
  map.fitBounds(bounds);

  var styles=[
  {
    featureType:"road",
    elementType:"labels",
    stylers:[
      {visibility:"off"}
    ]
  }
  ];
  map.setOptions({styles: styles});

var pinIcon = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
    'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png',
    null, /* size is determined at runtime */
    null, /* origin is 0,0 */
    null, /* anchor is bottom center of the scaled image */
    new google.maps.Size(52, 52)
);  

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: firstB,
      map: map,
      title: 'AVS',
      icon:pinIcon,
  }); 

  var firstB_contentString = '<div><p>Medical Office Building</p><a href="MOB/architectural-layout.html"><p class="infoContent">6007 E Woodmen Rd.</p><p class="infoContent">Colorado Springs, CO 80923</p></p></a></div>';

  var firstB_infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: firstB_contentString
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
  firstB_infowindow.open(map,marker);
});

  var smarker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: secondB,
      map: map,
      title: 'AVS',
      icon:'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png'
  }); 
  var secondB_contentString = '<div><p>General Hospital</p><a href="MAIN/architectural-layout.html"><p class="infoContent">6001 E. Woodmen Rd.</p><p class="infoContent">Colorado Springs, CO 80923</p></a></div>';

  var secondB_infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: secondB_contentString
  });
google.maps.event.addListener(smarker, 'click', function() {
  secondB_infowindow.open(map,smarker);
});

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'mousedown', function() {
  firstB_infowindow.close(map,marker);
  secondB_infowindow.close(map,smarker);
});
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mousedown', function() {
  firstB_infowindow.close();
  secondB_infowindow.close();
});
google.maps.event.addListener(smarker, 'mousedown', function() {
  firstB_infowindow.close();
  secondB_infowindow.close();
});

/*bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
bounds.extend(marker);
bounds.extend(smarker);
map.fitBounds(bounds);*/

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);


google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "resize", function() {
 google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
 map.fitBounds(bounds);
});
```

```css
html, body, #map-canvas {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map-canvas" style="border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
```