# Keeping Google map markers on screen when window resized

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a web page that contains a map with multiple markers, I am hoping I can find a way to keep all these markers on the screen when the window is resized or when viewed at different viewports.

I have tried the different solutions I have found on for this but it has resulted breaking the code in various ways.

Here is my code:

```
    function draw_map($id, $mark, $lat, $long, $zoom, $width, $height, $control, $map_type, $geo_codes) {
    #intialize output
    $output = '';
    #put together array
   // print_r($geo_codes);exit;

  $output .= "    
    <div id='truckmap' ></div>
    <script>
      function initMap() {
        var myLatLng = {lat: ".$lat.", lng: ".$long."};

        // Create a map object and specify the DOM element for display.
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('truckmap'), {
          center: myLatLng,
          scrollwheel: false,
          zoom: ".$zoom."
        }); ";

   foreach ($geo_codes as $key => $stop) {
     $output .= "
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: '".$stop['text']."'
        });
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: {lat: ".$stop['latitude'].", lng: ".$stop['longitude']."},
          title: '".$stop['opts']['title']."'
        });
        marker.addListener('click', function() {
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });";

   }

    $output .= "}</script><script src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCmXYC5YlrqIQXuJwfYe2xiyZjswOKxsZE&callback=initMap' async defer></script>  ";

    #return output
    return $output;
} #end function
```

My knowledge of javascript and PHP is limited so I could use all the help I can get!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add an event listener in for when the window resizes. Have you tried the solution presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29311641/5812391)?

I've stripped their fiddle down a little bit to help you work out the essentials you need to include to get your map working correctly. [You can find it here.](http://jsfiddle.net/1mnmxf0h/)

Code snippet:

```
var geocoder;
var map;
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

function initialize() {
  firstB = new google.maps.LatLng(38.9395799,-104.7168500999999);
  secondB = new google.maps.LatLng(38.9382571,-104.71727069999997);
  thirdB = new google.maps.LatLng(38.9382571,-99.71727069999997);
    bounds.extend(firstB);
    bounds.extend(secondB);
    bounds.extend(thirdB);

  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var mapOptions = {
    disableDefaultUI:true
  }

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
  map.fitBounds(bounds);


  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: firstB,
      map: map,
      title: 'AVS',     
  }); 

  var smarker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: secondB,
      map: map,
      title: 'AVS',
      icon:'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png'
  }); 

  var tmarker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: thirdB,
      map: map,
      title: 'AVS',
      icon:'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png'
  }); 
 }

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "resize", function() {
 google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
 map.fitBounds(bounds);
});
```

I suggest re-working your map slightly so it is initialised with the boundaries of your markers instead of passing the zoom and center in the function. I imagine if you have multiple maps or need to add markers then this would be a better solution than working out what zoom to pass in. You can also omit the latlng in the options as the fitBounds method works out where the center is, anyway.

You'll need to create more variables such as firstB, secondB for each of your makers and to extend the bounds object to include each of them. You can add all of that using a similar foreach function at the beginning of your initMap function.

**Updated:**
Try this, it should work for you:

```
        function draw_map($id, $mark, $lat, $long, $zoom, $width, $height, $control, $map_type, $geo_codes) {
$i = 1;
$output = '';
$output .= "    
<div id='truckmap' ></div>
<script>
function initMap() {
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        var myLatLng = {lat: ".$lat.", lng: ".$long."};
        // Create a map object and specify the DOM element for display.
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('truckmap'), {
        center: myLatLng,
        scrollwheel: false,
        zoom: ".$zoom."
    }); ";

    foreach ($geo_codes as $key => $stop) {
    $output .= "
    var marker".$i." = new google.maps.LatLng(".$stop['latitude'].",".$stop['longitude'].");
    bounds.extend(marker".$i.");
    var infowindow".$i." = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: '".$stop['text']."'
    });
    var marker".$i." = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: {lat: ".$stop['latitude'].", lng: ".$stop['longitude']."},
    title: '".$stop['opts']['title']."'
    });
    marker".$i.".addListener('click', function() {
    infowindow".$i.".open(map, marker".$i.");
    });";
    $i++;   
    }

    $output .= "map.fitBounds(bounds); google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'resize', function() {
 google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
 map.fitBounds(bounds);
});}</script><script src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCmXYC5YlrqIQXuJwfYe2xiyZjswOKxsZE&callback=initMap' async defer></script>  ";

    #return output
return $output;
} #end function
```

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your answer.  I did not write the original code posted here and I only know basic Javascipt, so I have no idea how to adapt your solution to my existing code...

Comment: Try the code I've put in the update and see if that works for you.

Comment: Ok, just spotted a problem - if I click on one of the pins on the map it will always open the first pin in the list, regardless of which one you clicked on.

Comment: Ah, that was an oversight. Re-edited it again so it should work now.

Comment: The pop-up works on all markers now, but the information that is showing in the pop up is still the data from the first map pin.

Comment: Updated again :)